# Max brightness on Ubuntu 18.04 is lower than Windows 10

Tags: brightness

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 on my old Lenovo P500 laptop. The max brightness is 10-20% lower on ubuntu than on windows. I tried everything i found so far on internet - nothing helped.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu there is a package named xrandr and it has an option for manage the brightness. But it need to know the output you have:

```
sudo apt install xrandr
xrandr
```

After that you type:

```
xrandr --output <your_output> --brightness <x>
```

You can replace "x" by the value you want. I use "1" or "1.2" in general. Your screen output on a laptop is eDP-1.